# Why isn't the vector $(4,3,2)$ a linear combination of the vectors $u_1=(2,1,-1)$ and $u_2=(1,1,1)?$

Tags: linear-algebra

So we are looking for scalars $x$ and $y$ such that

$$x(2,1,-1)+y(1,1,1)=(4,3,2),$$

which gives rise to the system

$$\left\{
  \begin{array}{rcr}
    2x+y & = & 4 \\
    x+y & = & 3 \\
-x+y &=& 2 
  \end{array}
\right.$$

Eliminating gives (adding row 2 to row 3)

$$\left\{
  \begin{array}{rcr}
    2x+y & = & 4 \\
    2y & = & 5 \\
  \end{array}
\right.$$

Which gives $y=\frac{5}{2}$ and $x=\frac 34.$

Comment: Never decrease the number of rows, unless you really know what you are doing. In your case, you should have kept either the second or the third row to properly solve the system resp. to see that it has no solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your linear system is overdetermined and has no solution.
We can write your system in the matrix form:
$$Ax = b$$
where
$$A =
        \begin{pmatrix}
        2 & 1 \\
        1 & 1 \\
        -1 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix},\quad
b = \begin{pmatrix}
        4 \\
        3 \\
        2 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
and $x$ is a 2 dimensional vector.

Then we can try to solve it by $QR$ decomposition: let $A=QR$, where $Q$ is an orthogonal $3\times3$ matrix and $R$ a $3\times2$ upper triangular matrix. If a solution $x$ exists, it must satisfy
$$
Rx = Q^Tb
$$

If you run the $QR$ decomposition on $A$, the last row of $R$ is all zero, therefore in order to have a $x$ that solves the system, the last row of $Q^Tb$ should also be zero. But it is not.

$$
Q = \begin{pmatrix}
        -0.81649658 & -0.21821789 &  0.53452248 \\
       -0.40824829 & -0.43643578 & -0.80178373 \\
       0.40824829 & -0.87287156 &  0.26726124
        \end{pmatrix} \implies
Q^Tb = \begin{pmatrix}
        -3.67423461 \\ -3.92792202 \\  0.26726124
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

So, there is no $x\in\mathbb{R}^2$ can solve $Rx = Q^Tb$ or $Ax = b$.

For reference,
$$
R = \begin{pmatrix}
       -2.44948974 & -0.81649658 \\
       0.        & -1.52752523 \\
       0.        &  0.        
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

---

Another way to look at it, following Christian Blatter's answer: find the normal direction of the plane:
$$
u_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
       2 \\ 1 \\ -1     
        \end{pmatrix},\quad
u_2 = \begin{pmatrix}
       1 \\ 1 \\ 1     
        \end{pmatrix},\implies
u_3 = \begin{pmatrix}
       2 \\ -3 \\ 1     
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
The project of $v=(4,3,2)$ on the normal direction is $v \cdot u_3 = 1$, $\neq 0$. There for $v$ is not in the plane spanned by $u_1$ and $u_2$.

Answer (score 5):

Eliminating does not eliminate a row. It uses one row to transform another row in order to eliminate variables from that row. So you either transform row 3 into $2y = 5$ and keep row 2, or you transform row 2 and keep row 3. And no matter which one you keep,  $y=\frac{5}{2}$ and $x=\frac 34$ violates that one.

Answer (score 2):

The two vectors $u_1$ and $u_2$ are obviously linearly independent, hence they span a plane in ${\mathbb R}^3$. The vector $a:=(4,3,2)$ is lying in this plane iff you can find scalars $x$ and $y$ such that $a=x\, u_1+y\, u_2$. Now the resulting system of **three** linear equations for the two unknowns $x$ and $y$ has **no** solutions. It follows that $a$ does not lie in said plane.

Answer (score 1):

Because $\dfrac34(2,1,-1) + \dfrac52(1,1,1) = \left(4,3.25,1.75\right)$.

Comment: I know, but wasn't I able to get something like $0=3$ in the last row to show that solutions don't exist? How could I get false solutions with elimination? I should not have to test the solutions in all three equations to see if the system has solutions or not.

Answer (score 1):

Define $        A=\begin{pmatrix}
        2 & 1 & 4\\
        1 & 1 & 3\\
        -1 & 1 &2\\
        \end{pmatrix}$
and 
$B =
        \begin{pmatrix}
        2 & 1 \\
        1 & 1 \\
        -1 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$

$\det A=1\ne 0$ so $\text{rank }A=3$ while $\text{rank }B=2\ne \text{rank }A$

The system is impossible

Hope this helps